# Which process retrieves the Slightlight xap file?

Tags: .net, silverlight, sharepoint

We're using silverlight on our SharePoint site. When someone navigates to the page containing the silverlight object, they are prompted for credentials. Other pages work fine.

I'm wondering if the client is trying to retrive the xap file (which is in a location the process hosting the web application has access to, but not the user).

Is the xap file retrieved by the IIS process or the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server (IIS in this case) retrieves the XAP file from disk and sends it to the client. The client retrieves the XAP file from the web server.

Answer (score 2):

The Client retrieves the XAP.  It is just like any other dependent item on the web page (image, css, js)